# Perl Script cant retrieve checkbox value

Tags: perl

I have the following Perl subs all in the same file -

populate:

```
sub __populate {
    my $self = shift;

    my $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("select prefid, value, others_posts from user_preferences where userid=?");
    $sth->execute($self->userid);
    while(my $href = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
        $self->value($href->{PREFID}, $href->{VALUE}, $href->{OTHERS_POSTS});
    }
    $sth->finish();
}
```

update:

```
sub update {
    my $self = shift;

    my $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("delete from user_preferences where userid=?");
    $sth->execute($self->userid);
    $sth->finish;
    $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("insert into user_preferences(userid, prefid, value, others_posts ) values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
    while(my ($prefid, $value, $others_posts) = each %{$self->{PREFS}}) {
        $sth->execute($self->userid, $prefid, $value, 'true');
    }
    $sth->finish;
}
```

and value:

```
sub value {
    my $self = shift;
    my $prefid = shift;
    $self->{PREFS}->{$prefid} = shift if(@_);
    return $self->{PREFS}->{$prefid};
}
```

Originally it was just `PREFID` and `VALUE` but I just added `OTHERS_POSTS` into the `populate` and `update` subs. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be returning anything for the `OTHERS_POSTS` that I just added. Every time the script runs, the values for `OTHERS_POSTS` doesn't get inserted into the table. I think the problem lies in my `value` sub but I'm fairy new with Perl and don't know how to modify it so that the value of `OTHERS_POSTS` gets extracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you have changed each preference from a simple key/value pair (prefid/value) to each key having two values (value & othersposts). Need to change your data structure accordingly to support that.

So each prefId key needs a hash containing VALUE & OTHERPOSTS entries with the relevant values.

Changes for this are:

```
sub update {
    my $self = shift;

    my $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("delete from user_preferences where userid=?");
    $sth->execute($self->userid);
    $sth->finish;
    $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("insert into user_preferences(userid, prefid, value, others_posts ) values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
    while(my ($prefid, $pref) = each %{$self->{PREFS}}) {
        $sth->execute($self->userid, $prefid, $pref->{VALUE}, $pref->{OTHERSPOSTS});
    }
    $sth->finish;
}

sub value {
    my ($self,$prefid,$value,$othersposts) = @_;
    $self->{PREFS}->{$prefid} = { VALUE => $value , 
                                  OTHERSPOSTS => $othersposts };
    return $self->{PREFS}->{$prefid};
}
```

__populate() dosn't need changing as you are already passing the extra parameter to value()

Haven't been able to actual run this so may be some syntex errors, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

`$self->{PREFS}` is a hash that originally had `prefid => value` pairs.

if you wanna store `value` and `other_posts` in that hash modify:

```
sub value {
    my ($self,$prefid,$value,$otherposts) = @_;

    # set
    if( ! defined($value)) {
        $self->{PREFS}->{$prefid} = "$value|$otherposts";
    }

    return $self->{PREFS}->{$prefid};
}
```

new version of update:

```
sub update {
    my $self = shift;

    my $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("delete from user_preferences where userid=?");
    $sth->execute($self->userid);
    $sth->finish;
    $sth = $self->{dbh}->prepare("insert into user_preferences(userid, prefid, value, others_posts ) values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
    for my $prefid (keys %{$self->{PREFS}}) {
        my ($value,$others_posts) = split '\|', $self->{PREFS}->{$prefid};
        $sth->execute($self->userid, $prefid, $value, $others_posts);
    }
    $sth->finish;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a very visual learner and fairly new to Perl. Would you be able to provide an example?